# How to scrap a loading item in pyhton

Tags: python, web-scraping, coingecko

I can't manage to scrape the dev github links on some coingecko's pages for it displays "loading" as output of the request. I've tried with request.get("https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/solpatrol-bail")

Here the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res=requests.get("https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/solpatrol-bail#developer")
cres=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
dev=cres.find_all("div", attrs={"id":"developer"})
dev
```

If someone has any idea on how to solve this I would be grateful thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the developer tab is loaded from this url: `https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/25787/developer_tab`. Which would make:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res=requests.get("https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/25787/developer_tab")
cres=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
dev=cres.find("a")['href']
dev
```

Output:

```
'https://github.com/SolPatrol/'
```

Comment: Oww indeed thanks, if no to much to ask where did you find that url?

Comment: Just check what happens in the [network tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) when clicking the developer tab on the page. You'll see that link pop up.

Comment: thx  a lot really useful!